# Import Firebase in dynamic Swift framework (with/without Cocoapods) and import framework into app target

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

[Firebase](http://firebase.google.com) for iOS is an Objective-C framework which recommends integration using Cocoapods. Here's how I'm trying to set it up:

I am running Xcode 8b6 on OS X 10.11.6. The app is being built with the iOS 10 SDK, targeting iOS 9.

`MyApp` is the regular (Swift) iOS app I want to use.

`MyFramework` is an embedded dynamic framework with the app, q. I would like all the Firebase code to be abstracted away into the framework, and therefore add Firebase to the `MyFramework` target in my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
end

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end
```

On running `pod install`, I am able to import Firebase in all `.swift` files in `MyFramework`. However, on using `import MyFramework` anywhere in my app, I get the error `Missing required module Firebase`.

Thinking this could be a Cocoapods issue, I started a fresh project and integrated Firebase manually, but ended up with the same issue.
Is this a known issue? If so, are there any fixes for it?

Comment: Same problem here...

Comment: Any luck ? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Has anyone found a solution yet? I'm facing the same issue and struggle since days

Comment: Hi @fruechtemuesli, check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47904050/5333674

Answer (score 1):

In the podspec of MyFramework, add dependency of the Firebase pods. Also set the static framework flag as `true`. This is how your podspec should look:

```
*OTHER METADATA RELATED TO MYFRAMEWORK*
s.static_framework = true
s.dependency   'Firebase'
s.dependency   'Firebase/Database'
s.dependency   'Firebase/Auth'`
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you can include this in your podfile

//As you are targeting iOS 9.0

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

def firebase_pods
 pod 'Firebase'
 pod 'Firebase/Database'
 pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end

target 'MyApp’ do
 firebase_pods
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you, i can try to help in other way i could