# Crash when Use Firebase Analytics in a project SDK Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoa-touch, firebase-analytics

I created a CocoaTouch Framework SDK, which uses the Firebase library for checking. However, I have the following problem:
- Added Firebase Analytics to the SDK, build successful, however if in SDK there is a function call in the class `FIRAnalytics`, for example:

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"share_image"
                    parameters:@{
                                 @"name": name,
                                 @"full_text": text
                                 }];
```

Then in Project A(example) using our SDK crashed in the function:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
```

- If our SDK does not call functions in the `FIRAnalytics` class, Project A will not crash
- We tried using Firebase directly in project A too not crashed
- I Integrate without CocoaPods

[image: Add Framework Firebase Analytics]

[image: Log]

Comment: Please don't show screenshots os textual content. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".

Comment: It has no error message, please help me

Comment: @VănHảiCao, Do you have GoogleService-Info.plist file in your A project? And before calling any firebase methods, first you must init firebase with [FIRApp configure];

Comment: @yvzzztrk i added file GoogleService-Info.plist in my A projecrt, and is already init FireBase [FIRApp configure]

Comment: @VănHảiCao, there is a README file in framework SDK zip https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks . Did you check all the steps in Integration Instructions?

Comment: @yvzzztrk I did so guide

Comment: Did you add  -ObjC flag to "Other Linker Settings"?

Comment: @PaulBeusterien i Did it

Comment: Thanks, I resovle problem Crash, by add FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled = NO in info.plist, but checking no data on Console FireBase

Comment: I think the problem is FIRAConditionalUserPropertyController doesn't have processEventOnWorkerQueue. Can you grep the binary of the framework to see if there is any symbol named "processEventOnWorkerQueue"? Also, where did you get the framework? Is it from the zip file?

Answer (score 1):

For people who wants to use firebase sdks in swift framework without cocoapods, I managed to resolve this crash by just adding following #import to framework's public header file "YourCocoaTouchFrameworkNameSwift.h"

```
#import <YourCocoaTouchFrameworkName/Firebase.h>
```

and also followed all the integration instructions in [README](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks) file.

You can checkout my sample cocoa touch framework and project on [github](https://github.com/yvzzztrk/FirebaseSampleCocoaTouchFrameworkSwift)

Comment: Hi @yvzzztrk. I'm getting a Missing required module 'Firebase' error. Any help?