# Firebase is not Importing without cocoapods in Xcode

Tags: firebase, swift4, xcode9

I am new at `Swift`. I am creating my own framework that will use `Firebase` for in-app messages.

I tried to install `Firebase` through `Cocoa` pods, but it has issues: when I do that for my framework, then for sample project I have to install Firebase again. And then I get the numbers of warnings like this: 
`Class Firebase is implemented in both /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/AD85D7EC-2652-4019-94FB-C799D0FBA69B/MyFrameworkExampleApp.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework (0x1019a0438) and /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AD85D7EC-2652-4019-94FB-C799D0FBA69B/MyFrameworkExampleApp.app/MyFrameworkExampleApp (0x10107c558). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.`

my app crashes at runtime due to these warnings

So I don't want to use cocoa pods in Framework but need `Firebase` in my project.)
.

I follow the steps:

"https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks"

I just download the firebase file and import it into my project. after this I try to:

`import Firebase`

at the top of my swift class but the compiler is giving me an error.

`No such module 'Firebase'`

I am using Xcode 9. swift 4.

All of the framework files are in

"Targets > FrameworkName > General > Linked Frameworkd and Libraries".

also in the

"Targets > FrameworkName > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries".

I also followed this tutorial:

http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/setting-up-firebase-without-cocoapods/

but nothing happened.

Where am I wrong and What should I do?

Comment: we all are learner so never say sorry at all. but try to improve your skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in firebase we have not a .framework file for import firebase. As we know that firebase is a combination of different frameworks, so we were unable to import firebase directly. thats why we

import required framework and dependent framework separately.
Dont try to import whole firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding following #import to framework's public header file "YourCocoaTouchFrameworkNameSwift.h"

```
#import <YourCocoaTouchFrameworkName/Firebase.h>
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47904050/5333674), if you need more information.

Comment: .!  i tried this... but its gave error
"Include of non-modular header inside framework module"